# question about equivalence of boolean statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Does the function $(p \land q) \lor r$ equal the function $p \land (q \lor r)$?

please it would be suitable if in your feedback you will include which algebraic rule for boolean function to follow..

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(p \land q) \lor r\equiv (p\lor r) \land (q\lor r)\tag{1}$$

$$p\land (q\lor r) \equiv (p\land q) \lor (p \land r)\tag{2}$$

In both cases, I applied a distributive law/rule.

To see more vividly that the two statements are not equivalent, take $p$ to be false, $r$true.  Then: Is statement $(1)$ true of false? What about statement $2$?

Comment: should i consider q to be  true or false

Comment: $q$ can be either true or false. If $p$ is false, $r$ true, $(p \land q) \lor r $ evaluates to $(p \land q) \lor True$ so is true, simply because $r$ is true. However, $p \land (q\lor r)$ is false, simply because $p$ is false. Recall that $False \land \text{anything}$ is false.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: please also help me in this 1 'Is the function ~((~p ^ q) V (~p ^ ~q)) V (p ^ q) equal to the function ~p?

Comment: First, think about accepting an answer. (Click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. Then, post your new question as a new question. But first, see if these hints help: Use DeMorgan's to distribute the front negation. Then use it again on each of the first two disjuncts. Alternatively, use a truth table for each statement, and see if their truth values under *every* truth value assignment to p, q match.

Answer (score 0):

What are the truth values of the two formulas when $p$ is false and $r$ is true?